# ANTLR : Tree parsing giving unexpected results

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to create my own ANTLR4 grammar so that I can parse some expressions, such as :

> *STARTS_WITH(this.sequence, "startSeq")*
>
> *ENDS_WITH("sequenceToTest", "endSeq")*

(I have a mix of constants and variables as function parameters).

The Lexer and Parser Rules have been created, but when I try to display the function *ToStringTree*, it seems like the tree is parsed in a wrong way.

I am using Antlr 4 with ASP.Net Core 2.1.

**The grammar file :**

```
grammar expression;

expression : bool_function (OPERATOR bool_function)* ;

bool_function : (FUNCTION_NAME PAR_OPEN parameter (COMMA parameter)* PAR_CLOSE) ;

parameter : constant | current_object_field ;

constant : DOUBLE_QUOTE ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE DOUBLE_QUOTE ;

current_object_field : THIS ALPHANUM ;

WHITESPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' |'\r' )+ -> skip ;

COMPARATOR : ('==' | '<=' | '>=' | '<>') ;

OPERATOR : ('&&' | '||') ;

PAR_OPEN : '(' ;

PAR_CLOSE : ')' ;

COMMA : ',' ;

DOLLAR : '$' ;

DOUBLE_QUOTE : '"' ;

THIS : 'this.' ;

NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;

ALPHANUM : [a-zA-Z_0-9]+ ;

ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE    : ~('"')+ ;

FUNCTION_NAME : ('STARTS_WITH' | 'ENDS_WITH' | 'CONTAINS' | 'EQUALS') ;
```

**The unit testing, trying to parse one basic expression :**

```
        try
        {
            expressionParser expressionParser = Setup("STARTS_WITH(this.sequence, \"startSeq\")");
            expressionParser.ExpressionContext expressionContext = expressionParser.expression();

            var a = expressionContext.ToStringTree(expressionParser);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var a = e.Message;
            throw;
        }
```

The output I receive for parsing my expression via *ToStringTree* is the following :

```
(expression (bool_function STARTS_WITH(this.sequence,  " startSeq " )))
```

But I would expect a result, going deeper, such as :

```
(expression (bool_function STARTS_WITH((parameter(current_objet_field this.sequence)),(parameter(constant "startSeq")))))
```

Are there any obvious mistakes in the way I defined my Lexer/Parser ?

Comment: Do you get any syntax errors?

Comment: No, I dont have any syntax error while executing this code :-(

Comment: When I just tested your grammar on your input, I got the error "line 1:0 mismatched input 'STARTS_WITH(this.sequence, ' expecting FUNCTION_NAME". So I believe you do get an error, but you're not seeing it. Are you running your application in a way that you'd see its stderr output? If not, you should add your own error handler that will inform you of errors in a way that you'll notice.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added the try catch I'm using during my tests (no exception thrown) Am I missing something in my ANTLR unit test ?

Comment: The default error listener does not throw an exception - it just prints the error to stderr and continues parsing (returning a tree where some of the fields may be `null` when they couldn't be parsed correctly). You can check whether there were errors (and how many there were) using `parser.NumberOfSyntaxErrors`. For tests, I'd recommend using an error listener that collects all error messages in a set and then checks that you got the right number of errors with the right messages (for input that's supposed to produce errors).

Comment: For input that's supposed to parse, you can use an error listener that asserts `false` with a message that contains the error message from ANTLR. You could also just assert that the number of errors is 0,  but then you wouldn't see the message of the syntax error in the test output.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've checked NumberOfSyntaxErrors, which has a value of 1 as you found out in your own tests. Do you have any documentation of an implementation of an error listener with ANTLR ? I'm rather newbie regarding that topic..

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/sepp2k/minicomp/blob/master/src/main/java/minicomp/Compiler.java) where I've stored errors in a list. This is in Java, not C#, but I hope it's helpful anyway. As for documentation, there are the [official API docs](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BaseErrorListener.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the tree you want because your input isn't parsed correctly at all. The parse fails with the following syntax error:

> line 1:0 mismatched input 'STARTS_WITH(this.sequence, ' expecting FUNCTION_NAME

So the first thing you should check, is why you didn't see the error message. The default error listener will print syntax errors to stderr. If you're running in an environment where you don't see stderr, you should install your own error listener that informs the user of syntax errors in the input in a way that will be noticeable.

Now why does the input not parse? Well, the error message seems suspicious because it's complaining about a missing `FUNCTION_NAME` at the beginning when that's exactly what `STARTS_WITH` is (or should be, at least). It also seems to treat `STARTS_WITH(this.sequence,` as a single token, which is clearly not what we want. So something seems to be amiss with your lexer rules.

The first thing you should do when you think the lexer might be producing the wrong tokens, is to actually print out the tokens produced by the lexer. You can do that using `grun` with the `-tokens` option (that requires you to go through Java, but that's not much of a problem since your grammar contains no actions) or by iterating over the token stream in your C# code (note that you'll have to reset the stream after iterating over it or else the parser will only see an empty stream).

By doing this, we'll see that the following tokens have been produced by the lexer:

```
[@0,0:26='STARTS_WITH(this.sequence, ',<ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE>,1:0]
[@1,27:27='"',<'"'>,1:27]
[@2,28:35='startSeq',<ALPHANUM>,1:28]
[@3,36:36='"',<'"'>,1:36]
[@4,37:37=')',<')'>,1:37]
[@5,38:37='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:38]
```

Now the first problem we can see here is the `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE` token in the beginning. Clearly we want this to be  multiple tokens, none of which are `ANY_BUT_DOBULE_QUOTE`. This happens because `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE` can match the entire string `STARTS_WITH(this.sequence,` whereas `FUNCTION_NAME` would only match `STARTS_WITH`. ANTLR-generated lexers follow the maximum munch rule, which says to always use the rule that produces the longest match (using the one that comes first in the grammar in case of ties).

The other problem is `startSeq` being an `ALPHANUM` since the only thing that your grammar allows between two double quotes is `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE`. Here the lexer produced an `ALPHANUM` instead of `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE` because both rules would have produced a match of the same length, but `ALPHANUM` comes first in the grammar. Note that if you simply switch around the order of `ALPHANUM` and `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE`, the lexer will never produce an `ALPHANUM` token, which is also not what you want.

Both of these issues stem from the fact that `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE` can match basically anything and thus overlaps with most of your other rules. This is a bad thing.

What you should be doing instead is to have a single lexer rule for string literals (so turn `constant` into a lexer rule and turn `DOUBLE_QUOTE` and `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE` into fragments or inline them directly into `CONSTANT`). That way there's no longer an `ANY_BUT_DOUBLE_QUOTE` rule that conflicts with everything and `CONSTANT` won't conflict with anything because it's the only rule that starts with a double quotes. This will also prevent white space from being discarded inside double quotes.

Once you've done that, you'll get an error about `STARTS_WITH` being an `ALPHANUM` instead of a `FUNCTION_NAME`, but you can fix that by moving `FUNCTION_NAME` before `ALPHANUM` in the grammar. Note that means that your function names can never be used as the names of members. If you don't want that, you should not make function names keywords (i.e. you should just allow arbitrary identifiers as function names and then check later whether you know a function with that name) or make them contextual keywords (have a parser rule that can match either an `ALPHANUM` or any of the function names).

Comment: You have been of a massive help, both for the error output issue (Error Listener) and to help me understand how ANTLR work; I thought ANTLR had a top-bottom approach, first trying to match some parser rules, and then going deeper in the defined lexer rules. But as you explained, it's the other way round, first trying to match lexer rules in some greedy way, and then reconstructing the tree with the parser rules. \n Is there a way to chose the top-bottom rather than the bottom-top approach ?

Comment: @zurk The lexer works completely independently from the parser. There is no way for the parser to tell the lexer "only try to match one of the following rules this time". In fact, you can run the lexer on its own without invoking the parser and you'll know that the sequence tokens it gives you will be the same ones it would give to the parser. There are lexer modes, which allow you to apply a different set of rules after seeing certain tokens, but those are still solely controlled by the lexer (meaning you can only switch modes after a given token, not a given non-terminal).

Comment: So no, there is no way to control the lexer from the parser. Note that the parser itself does work in a top-down fashion that just doesn't extend to the interactions between the parser and the lexer.

Comment: OK I get now that the lexer tokens are independently constructed thanks to some 'precedence' rules and such, and the parser will emit potential errors when this set of tokens is submitted to its own parser rules. Thanks again for your time :)